# How do I save the user data to database (Spring 6, Spring Boot 3, Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am using Spring boot to test OAuth with Google and Github. I am able to get the login details but I do not know how to save the data to a database. I have created a User entity of the following structure

```
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String email;

    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

My security configuration for Spring security is as follows. I have tried saving the principal values to an instance of user but it shows error saying

```
class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser cannot be cast to class com.axis.springauthtest.entity.User
```

The Security configuration is as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return  http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(httpSecurityOAuth2LoginConfigurer -> {
                    httpSecurityOAuth2LoginConfigurer.successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                            System.out.println("Login Successful");
                            System.out.println(authentication.getPrincipal());


                        }
                    });
                })

                .build();
    }


}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the code, which saves to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

your cod it is good but not complete , you need to add annotation.
in user class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String id
```

and to make a easy contact (save) make a

> Repository Interface

like this

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
User findByUsername(String username);
```

or

```
Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);}
```

User it is the class name and String it is the ID datatype
and you need to Create a Implement UserDetailsService class

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws     UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getPassword(),
            // Add authorities/roles if needed
            Collections.emptyList()    );  }
public void saveUser(User user) {
    userRepository.save(user); }}
```

and you need class Controller , if you look the spring website document , you will write and see class control but I think this will be good for your code .

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/register")
public class RegistrationController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    userService.saveUser(user);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("User registered successfully");
```

and you have configure Spring Security properly for user authentication and authorization.
so that all your code
try this and show the result please